# how to covert a java class type to its base type?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to convert a class type to its base type so that the java program can be compiled. In detail, we have code as follows. The code is similar to  https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/develop/chill-thrift/src/main/java/com/twitter/chill/thrift/TBaseSerializer.java#L56

```
  interface TBase {.... }

  class Deserializer {
      public TBase read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<TBase> tBaseClass) {...}
      ...
  }

  class Event implements TBase {.... }


  Deserializer = new Deserializer(...)
  deserializer.read(kryo, input, Event.class);
```

I got the following errors with java8:

```
incompatible types: Class<Event> cannot be converted to Class<TBase>
```

We cannot change TBase interface to a class. With that constaint, how shall I resolve this type compatibility issue? Is  `Class<Event>` also `Class<TBase>` ?

I have also tried to declare `Class<? extends TBase>` as the parameter type. with this approach, I got "'read(Kryo, Input, Class)' in 'TBaseSerializer' clashes with 'read(Kryo, Input, Class)' in 'com.twitter.chill.thrift.TBaseSerializer'; both methods have the same erasure, yet neither override the other.

Comment: By passing in `TBase.class`, because that's what your method is defined to accept. What does the method do with the class object?

Comment: TBase.class is an interface. Passing that class causes other issue.

Comment: So maybe you want `Class<? extends TBase>` instead? What does the method do with the class object? No, `Class<Event>` is not a `Class<TBase>`.

Comment: Your `Event.class` will **never** be an instance of `Class<TBase>`. Only `TBase.class` is an instance of `Class<TBase>`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use wildcards here

```
public TBase read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<? extends TBase> tBaseClass) {...}
```

it means that anything that is derived from TBase can be passed as an argument. you can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcards-in-java/)

Comment: with this approach, I got "'read(Kryo, Input, Class<? extends TBase>)' in 'TBaseSerializer' clashes with 'read(Kryo, Input, Class<TBase>)' in 'com.twitter.chill.thrift.TBaseSerializer'; both methods have the same erasure, yet neither override the other.